# Open database and hande errors

Tags: c#, exception-handling

How to make this code better?

```
if (Program.Data.DataBase.TryOpenDataBase())
{
 bool result; 
 DataBase= new Program.Data.DataBase(out result);
 if (!result)
 {
    if (Program.DataBase!= null) 
       Program.DataBase.Dispose();
     Program.DataBase= null;
     Log.WriteERROR("Can not open database");
     Application.Exit();
     return;
 }
 else
 {
    Log.WriteERROR("Can not open database");
    Application.Exit();
    return;
 }
```

Comment: There's a lot of stuff here that appears to be proprietary and has no real meaning in a usable context. Are you using MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle? What does `TryOpenDataBase()` look like? What is `DataBase`?

Answer (score 4):

I would remove the out parameter from the constructor. It is really confusing to read. Maybe create a function that throws an exception instead. If the database implements IDisposable you can use a using block instead.

**Edit -** You have some duplicate code as well:

```
Log.WriteERROR("Can not open database");
Application.Exit();
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you shouldn't return any error codes, use exceptions and try/catch blocks.

Comment: To be clear, returning the error code doesn't just have be the return value of the method, it could be an out parameter. This is still usually a bad thing.